# How does one remove FUSE from a MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, beta-seed-program

[image: I get this message whenever I startup Mac]

How do you remove FUSE? I have FUSE on my MacBook Pro (don't remember why I needed it or installed it) and when I installed Mojave Beta I keep getting this message upon startup. As there doesn't seem to be a compatible version yet, how do I get rid of it? Thx.

Comment: How did you install it? Homebrew Cask?

Comment: Oddly enough It is in my install of Mojave (Public Beta) and I have never installed it either.

Comment: @nimesh I'm not sure I would even know how to do that. I believe it installed with an app but I cannot be sure. I did a total wipe and reinstall of OS so not sure where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences >> Fuse, there's a "Remove Fuse" button.

[image: Fuse Preferences Panel]

Clicking remove should remove it completely.  Also, [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) might be a good bet.

Comment: Thanks for the response...the issue with this method is that FUSE is not shown in my System Prefs pane, nor does it show up in a Spotlight search. I have tried App Cleaner, which I suppose got rid of it but the alert I screenshot-ed above has still been coming up.

Comment: Was this an upgrade or a clean install?

Comment: It was a clean install

Comment: I wonder if they're going to include it now as part of macOS (like many other open source projects).  Looking at the license, it's BSD which allows them to integrate it into their product without releasing the source for everything back (why Bash is not 4.x).  https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/blob/master/LICENSE.txt  If that's the case, what you're seeing is probably a bug...